# ssrs 2008 export to excel leaves Column one as blank

Tags: ssrs-2008

ssrs 2008 export to excel leaves Column one as blank. when i tried to export file from SSRS to Excel its exporting data in column 2 making column 1 blank. it export the full data but instead of paste value in column 1 it pasting it to column 2. is there any specific reason. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

There must be a condition which must be something like this
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL",TRUE,FALSE) for column visibility. Hence when it is exporting to excel, it must be hiding the column.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, but how to fixed it now, i am new to SSRS. just i want my data to be export from column 1. its not hiding any column just it export data from column 2 of excel instead of column 1 Please help

Comment: IN SSRS Editor,go to the column which is blank in excel -> click on it ->F4(Properties) -> Visibility(it will be down)-> Remove any expressions for Hidden property and Update it as False. This should help.